# Translation of "Quasi non sit veritate"

Tags: idiom, latin-to-english-translation

> Quasi non sit veritate.

Searched and could not find anything.
Thanks in advance to those that can help translating.
This is from a “Tactical” training company.

Answer (score 2):

*quasi* means "as if", *non* means "not", *sit* is the third person singular present subjunctive of *esse* ("to be") and thus can mean "it were", *veritate* is the ablative singular of *veritas* ("truth") and thus can mean "in truth, really", so the total phrase means more or less "as if it really weren't".